# What does "posted out" exactly mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, british-english

I have received an email from my university about my graduation documents.
They wrote that:

> Degree Certificates and Diploma Supplements will be sent out by post in January.
> You will then be contacted by us to confirm that your documents have been posted out.

Does "***posted out***" in this context mean "*sent* (by the uni)" or "*received* (by me)"?

Comment: They send the documents. You receive them. They call you to confirm that you have received them. I can't find any valid examples of "post out", though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**posted out is British English** to post something out.

**mailed out is American English** to mail something out.

Here is **posted out** in a British university document:

Students are not eligible for another set of documents free of charge where:
 the documents were posted out more than six months ago;
 the documents were posted out to an address outside of the UK and less than 6 weeks
have passed

[Essex University](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/students/graduation/documents/award-docs-policy.pdf)

Comment: Nice example! That explains it well. And indeed, it is a British university. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since there is no entries for "post something out" in any dictionary, could you explain what it means (specifically what "out" means in this phrasal verb)? Does it mean to send something to many people at the same time?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko No, it just means to send something to someone by post (BrE) or by mail (AmE). It could be one or many.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a US university, it is badly worded.  I am a native US-English and am wondering if the writer invented the phrase "post out."  In context, however, it is clear that they are referring to confirming the date the document is mailed, not the date of receipt.

They say the mailing was to take place in January, and it is now February.  If you have not received a notification, you should contact them to confirm that they have mailed the documents.

Comment: That makes sense. I've already emailed them and got the above automated reply. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Morally, they should have responded by now, but two weeks after January 31 is not a completely unreasonable amount of time to work through bureaucracy and inform all the recipients by email, given recent problems with the US mail system.  After about February 14, I personally would begin escalating my desire for a more informative response.  For example: "You said in your email that the documents would be sent out in January and that the recipients would be notified by email.  Two weeks have passed since the end of the month, and I have received nothing but an uninformative automated reply."

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I appreciate your help.